# Xcode Label with long Text not properly shown

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, storyboard

This is my first IOS app, just for training, and I got some issue with Label ,check the image [image]

As you can See  **Object: Photo- Visualizing the Thomas Walther** is not properly shown and some words are missing. 
So How to fix it and make the string appears on multiLines if it's too long?

Comment: Change the attributes of the label.

Comment: I've changed the  height and width but same issue

Comment: You can change the number of lines, the font size, the rules for splitting a line, and several other things.  Learn to consult [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UILabel_Class/) before asking a basic question here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your storyboard, select the UILabel and open the Attributes Inspector (in the utilities, which can be opened with the shortcut opt-command-4). You can change all the the basic properties of the UILabel here.

For multiple lines, ensure that the label height is large enough and set the *Lines* to 0. You can also change the font scaling in the *Autoshrink* property (default is fixed font size).

I can't really tell from your screenshot, but you may have some Auto Layout issues with the width of your label to the right side of the window. So you may want to look into setting Auto Layout constraints as well.

Comment: Thank's I tried that but always getting same issue I think the right border are not well configured

Comment: From your screenshot, it looks like your label is extending off the right side of the window. Have you tried resetting your views to the suggested constraints?

Comment: Constraint for the Cell are by default I'm using TableView and I can't change them

Comment: I've fixed the right side issue but my text I not going on MultiLines I have changed the Hieght for my Label and I settled LinesNumber attributes at 0

Comment: Try changing *Line Breaks* to Word Wrap.

Comment: It was some constraint issue and auto layout